# Capture a screenshot of an inactive tab using the Chrome DevTools API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a Chrome extension where I have to take a screenshot using the tab ID, even when it's not an active tab. Therefore, I can't use the captureVisibleTab API. Is there a way to do this using Chrome debug mode? I've already tried capturing when the tab is active, but it doesn't work when it's inactive. Is there any workaround for this?

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot

Comment: What leads you to think this is even possible?  I don't think the browsers maintain a pixel image of inactive tabs.  They'll just refresh the display from the object model.

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible, but if I am able to run chrome.scripting.executeScript and get the HTML of an inactive tab, then it makes sense that this should work, right? In fact, I tried injecting content-script.js to capture the screenshot using html2canvas. It is working, but the HTML appears messed up and is not reliable.

Comment: That's all there is, as far as I know.  It doesn't render the HTML until it actually has to display it.

Comment: 1. Show your code. 2. Try changing `fromSurface` parameter.